# How to add env variables as time.sleep in python

Tags: python

I am exporting LOG_INTERVAL value as 5. How can I add this env value in python as `time.sleep`?

```
import os
import time
print("Goodbye, World!")
time.sleep(os.environ.get('LOG_INTERVAL'))
```

```
error:- Goodbye, World!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in 
    time.sleep(os.environ.get('LOG_INTERVAL'))
TypeError: a float is required
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you get from the environment is a string. You have to convert it to a number in order for it to be an acceptable value for `time.sleep()`

```
time.sleep(float(os.environ.get('LOG_INTERVAL'))
```

Comment: And if the var is not defined this crashes

Comment: You can easily fix that by adding a default to `.get()`. If the variable is defined but not a number, that's harder. Maybe wrap this in a `try`/`expect` but really, what can you do other than terminate with an error? Maybe print an error message explaining this in simple terms for unsophisticated users;

Answer (score 3):

```
time.sleep(float(os.environ.get('LOG_INTERVAL', 0))
```

I added the default `0` to @tripleee 's reply, so if the variable is not defined, your code doesn't crash.

Answer (score -1):

I think `LOG_INTERVAL` will be returned as a string.
Check it's type with `type(os.environ.get('LOG_INTERVAL'))`
If it is an int or a string containing nothing but numbers or fullstops `time.sleep(float(os.environ.get('LOG_INTERVAL')))` should convert it to a float and do the trick.